# Where does this yellowish shadow artefact come from?

Tags: artifacts, sunrise

I only notice this yellow shade after creating a HDR (Near the top of the building in the foreground. The image in this question is cropped from the oirginal)

[image]

I didn't notice before because HDR makes it stand out.

Here is the original 0 ev image

[image]

I have checked other images capture by the same camera and I did not see the same yellow stain. I can rule out it is a hardware issue.

I want to learn how this artefact happens? I am not pointing into the Sun directly or in its general direction.

If it is not easy to spot on a monitor, I will definitely miss it on the LCD display of my camera. Understanding how it happens can help me to avoid taking photo I might find useless in the future.

The photos were captured in the morning around 7:26am local time.

Comment: @twalberg knowing this place well, yes, off to the right is correct. This photo is looking roughly North East

Comment: @damnedtruths Yes, you're right.

Comment: @twalberg To my right hand side. It is not yet high up in the sky. I have already put a len hood on. Is there anything else I can do to avoid len flare?

Comment: A lens hood can't completely eliminate flare in all circumstances. Usually the best way to avoid it completely is to make sure the sun is at least 90 degrees away from your shooting direction (except for really wide angle lenses) if not behind you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it's lens flare, caused by the sunlight just managing to hit the lens, even with your lens hood on. Exacerbated by the HDR process.

You might not notice it as you're taking the shot, but if you wave your hand in front, above & to the side & see if you can spot any point where it changes the light balance in the viewfinder without being in shot, that's the spot where it shades the lens & removes the flare.
It's easier to spot if it flashes on/off as you're waving.

Or stand with the lens completely in the shade, if there is any.